# How to get a Map value to the tiles jsp page from main jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, collections, jsp-tags, tiles

Actually I'm trying to get a map values into tiles page lhsListing.jsp from a mainpage.jsp page. Is there any way to pass a map object. Here bellow my code Please help me somebody to get.

**mainPage.jsp**

```
<c:forEach var="lhsSrcMap" varStatus="status" items="${lhsListMap}">  
  <tiles:insert page="/jsp/common/lhsListing.jsp" >  
  <tiles:put name="lhsSrcMap" value="${lhsSrcMap}"/>
</tiles:insert>
```

**lhsListing.jsp**

```
<c:set var="lhsSrcMap"><tiles:get name="lhsSrcMap"/></c:set>
<c:forEach var="fieldRec" varStatus="status"items="${lhsSrcMap.value['LIST']['SRC_DTL_MAPS_LIST']['FIELD_LIST']}" > 

//something  

</c:forEach>
```

**Error shows in a page:**

> Can't insert page '${lhsSrcMap}' : null [ServletException in:/jsp/common/lhsListing.jsp] An error occurred while evaluating custom action attribute "items" with value "${lhsSrcMap.value['LIST']['SRC_DTL_MAPS_LIST']['FIELD_LIST']}": Unable to find a value for "value" in object of class "java.lang.String" using operator "." (null)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got a solution for my question.
> we can use [Implicit Objects](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaif) of the [Unified Expression Language](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html).
>
> I used **`scope="request"`** in JSTL.

**mainpage.jsp**

```
<c:forEach var="lhsSrcMap" varStatus="status" items="${lhsListMap}">  
   <c:set var="tileLhsSrcMap" value="lhsSrcMap" scope="request"/>
   <tiles:insert page="/jsp/common/lhsListing.jsp" >  
   
   </tiles:insert>
</c:forEach>
```

**lhsListing.jsp**

```
<c:forEach var="fieldRec" varStatus="status" items="${tileLhsSrcMap.value['LIST']['SRC_DTL_MAPS_LIST']['FIELD_LIST']}" > 

//something  

</c:forEach>
```

or  use **requestScope**

**lhsListing.jsp**

```
<c:forEach var="fieldRec" varStatus="status" items="${requestScope.tileLhsSrcMap.value['LIST']['SRC_DTL_MAPS_LIST']['FIELD_LIST']}" > 

//something  

</c:forEach>
```